# Can you tell me how to use InvokeScriptTransaction

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

This is an example of the WAVES IDE.
Please tell me how to use InvokeScriptTransaction to execute ‘func divideAmount ()’.

```
# waves IDE example
let Alice = Address(base58'3NBVqYXrapgJP9atQccdBPAgJPwHDKkh6A8')
let Bob = Address(base58'3N78bNBYhT6pt6nugc6ay1uW1nLEfnRWkJd')

@Callable(i)
func divideAmount() = {

    let transferAmount = wavesBalance(this) / 2

    TransferSet([
                ScriptTransfer(Alice, transferAmount, unit),
                ScriptTransfer(Bob, transferAmount, unit)
    ])
}
```

I set a script for my account on the test net.
However, I do not understand that it calls with InvokeScriptTransaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [IDE](https://ide.wavesplatform.com) you can run in the console. It is also available in the JS library ([waves-transactions](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-api-and-sdk/client-libraries/waves-transactions.html)).

```
broadcast(invokeScript({contractAddress: {CONTRACT_ADDRESS_HERE}), call:{function:"divideAmount",args:[]}, payment: []}))
```